# Can "parchive" be used for block devices?

Tags: backup, block-device, checksum, integrity

As explained on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parchive) and [Arch linux wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Parchive) "Parchive"s can be used to generate additional data for a `file`, that can be used in verification and even to some degree for repair/recovery of said file in case it has become partly corrupted (i.e. lets say a 4K block of a HDD becomes unreadable).

Considering the effort (both CPU and memory to store the extra redundancy repair data), is there a way use the concept of parchive as well on block devices. I would imagine

`/dev/sdX` having two partitins `/dev/sdX1` being 90% of the storage and `/dev/sdX2` containing the `par2` data for related to the content of `/dev/sdX1`.

Considering the value that can be seen in sacrifizing some CPU and storage for increased data integrity, I would imagine there to be even a linux kernel module (e.g. related to `device mapper` functionality) that would offer such a feature (maybe this is partly the `software raid` feature?)

Lastly and a related aspect to the question. Do any common filesystems employ such a parchive mechanism to protect against data loss (i.e. to due bit rot, or other corruption of blocks)? (I know that `zfs` boasts some sort of protection, and `ext4` is known to store multiple copies of important things like the `superblock` making it likely that to also feature a `parchive`-like feature?)

Comment: Even if it consumed CPU, this would be a very valuable feature for Btrfs to implement. Perhaps as a background service, like autodefrag. A little parity can go a long way toward preserving data integrity.

Comment: Overtime the probability of an entire file being corrupt is extremely low. While the probability of a single byte being corrupt is extremely  high. Using parity files makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 1):

Parchive/par2 take a *long* time to compute parity data. E.g., I use par2 for burning files to Blu-ray, at around 10% parity data it takes on the order of an hour on a somewhat-recent machine. That scales (not sure if linearly or worse) with the amount of data and the amount of parity, so to do it for a reasonable-sized block device would take days. I'm not sure if there is a way, mathematically, to optimize changing a file, otherwise any write would take a full parity recompute.

There are alternative parity schemes normally used on block devices: both RAID5 and RAID6 are parity schemes. Most RAID systems (both software and hardware) support them.